# View detailed main profile settings for existing account in Mail

Tags: windows-10, email, email-client

I've got a working email account configured for my work email in the Mail app in Windows 10 on my home PC.

I've got a new phone and want to set it up but can't find the details of the account in my emails, and in the Mail app I cannot see anything other than my email address... I need to enter server and so on:

[image]

How can I find the details for the account I already set up? Where are they hidden?

Comment: Did you try to configure it automatically using Outlook?

Comment: Yup, I know it needs more than just the email

Comment: If it is an exchange , try:  mail.yoursite.co.uk